# ImportError: cannot import name 'TelField' from 'wtforms'

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

Out of curiosity, I'm trying to use the html 5 widget TelField of Flask WTF.
However, I get the following error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'TelField' from 'wtforms'

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, TelField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, EqualTo, Length, Optional
from wtforms.widgets.html5 import TelInput
```

```
class SignupForm(FlaskForm):
    ...

    phone = TelField('Phone', validators=[Length(min=10), DataRequired()])

    ...
    submit = SubmitField('Signup')
```

```
<fieldset class="phone">
  {{ form.phone.label }}
  {{ form.phone(placeholder='+27123456789') }}
  {% if form.phone.errors %}
     <ul class="errors">
        {% for error in form.phone.errors %}
           <li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}
     </ul>
        {% endif %}
</fieldset>
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong with this. Any pointers would be greatly welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your import line should be:

`from wtforms.fields import TelField`

Do not use html5 at the end.  It's deprecated and may throw errors

Answer (score 1):

this import errors happen because of the new versions of WTForms.
my suggestion is ->

```
pip install wtforms==2.3.3
```

install this old version.

Answer (score 0):

Your import line should be:

```py
from wtforms.fields.html5 import TelField
```